# comparison Operators in thinking Sphinix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a model with attributes start_date and end_date. I have search form where user will put the date and I should get a data from the model if date is in between start_date and end_date.

how should I create a query with thinking sphinx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do something like the following:

- Add both start_date and end_date as [attributes](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html#attributes) (not fields) to your model's Sphinx index.
- Translate form params into a date or time value
- Use range [filters](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#filters) to limit search queries.

I've opted for very large windows of time, but essentially this ensures the given date is equal to or larger than the start date **and** less than or equal to the end date.

```
beginning, ending = Time.utc(1970), Time.utc(2030)
Model.search :with => {
  :start_date => beginning..date_from_params,
  :end_date   => date_from_params..ending
}
```

Comment: thanks pat .this helped me.
is there anyway to add sql query to the ThinkingSphinx::Search result.

Comment: You can send through some options for the resulting SQL query - `:include`, `:joins`, `:select`, `:order`, as noted in the documentation: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/searching.html#advanced - but that doesn't have any option for adding to the `WHERE` clause (which wouldn't be recommended anyway - it would screw up the pagination logic for Sphinx).